# Bing maps sdk with Telerik UI controls for universal app

Tags: c#, telerik, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Hi I am using Telerik UI controls for universal application .Since windows phone 8.1 has its own control for map so I used that but when I added bing maps sdk extension to windows 8.1 project and build it it shows following error

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Telerik.UI.Xaml.Grid\Themes\Resources.xbf'. Source files: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for Windows Universal Q3 2014\SDKs\Windows 8.1\Telerik UI for Windows Universal\Redist\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Telerik.UI.Xaml.Grid\Themes\Resources.xbf
C:\Develop\Reality.cz\Reality.cz - Universal\Reality.cz - Universal\Reality.cz - Universal.Windows\bin\Debug\Telerik.UI.Xaml.Grid\Themes\Resources.xbf  Reality.cz - Universal.Windows".
```

When I remove references for Bing Map and MS Visual C++ Runtime, I rebuild with success.

I search this on Telerik forum it says to add reference to binary files directly as shown in [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/error-payload-contains-two-or-more-files-with-the-same-destination-path)

When I added binary directly in reference tab it built successfully but thrown an exception at runtime

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in UniversalApp.Salik.Windows.exe but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: Requested Windows Runtime type 'Bing.Maps.Bing_Maps_XamlTypeInfo.XamlMetaDataProvider' is not registered.

Need help for solving that stuck here for a long time . 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the path of SDK folder (right click on referenced telerik library in project and see properties) and copy binaries folder to a another location
2. Uninstall Telerik Universal App SDK
3. Open you project and remove Telerik Library from references (which should be giving exclamation mark since the SDK is removed now)
4. Now add the reference of libraries from the folder you copied binaries into. (In my case, i referenced two libraries 'Telerik.Core.dll' and 'Telerik.UI.Xaml.Primitives.dll')

And it worked.